# Can you append a NSMutableArray to a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, nsmutablearray, append

I am trying to write some data from an NSMutableArray to a plist, while keep the old plists content.

The function `writeToFile:atomically:` overwrites the old contents with the new, I want to append the objects in the new array to the plist.

How can this be done? Thank you.

How can you check for duplicates while doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could load the contents of the file into an array, then use `addObjectsFromArray:` in your MutableArray to load the contents into that, then use the writeToFile feature.

i.e.

```
NSArray *oldArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[newMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:oldArray];

.....

[newMutableArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I think I'm going to go with this, as it seems to be simpler. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 This is the only way to do this and maintain the structure of the array in the file.

Answer (score -1):

Just create use an instance of `NSFileHandle` and use `-seekToEndOfFile`, then do your writing from the array.

Comment: -1 This will append data to the end of the file but it will be unusable gibberish and not a serialized NSMutableArray.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I first thought about.